# iOS app BLE sending crash report

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, crash-reports

I need some help please. I sent a very simple app for iPod to a company, to recognize a tracker via Bluetooth and upload some data to a web site. We tested, they tested and it was working just fine.
I got an email this morning, saying that the app crashes and they are sending me the crash reports, as below. I got 16 of them. I have asked for more info from them, but they didn't answer yet.

- My first question is : What on earth is that? How did they get a crash report?
- What does this crash report mean excepted I can see through SIGABRT that the app DID crash.
  I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance, sorry, the crash report is a bit big.

```
Incident Identifier: F77F6A7B-8760-40C5-9FD7-FE0ED070979A
CrashReporter Key:   5ca25de017263d20a80e56e0a295f17e9429e5c3
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:             XXX TRACKER [217]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B4D46780-38A9-47EA-942F-AC997C6BB357/XXX TRACKER.app/XXX TRACKER
Identifier:          co.uk.XXX.XXX-TRACKER
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-25 11:15:21.723 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-09-25 11:14:30.408 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2c2de132 0x3a23ac72 0x2c2de078 0x2cf56e1e 0xdedf2 0x2bfa04d6 0x2bfa096e 0x2bfab2a4 0x3a7a4c7e 0x3a7a4c6a 0x3a7af4ce 0x3a7aed9c 0x3a7b01b0 0x2c2a3884 0x2c2a1fa4 0x2c1ed99c 0x2c1ed7ae 0x3399f1a4 0x2f978690 0xdf89e 0x3a7e2aaa)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8a8df0 0x3a894000 + 85488
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a929c92 0x3a926000 + 15506
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a847934 0x3a7fe000 + 301364
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39a46bb8 0x39a46000 + 3000
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39a6066a 0x39a46000 + 108138
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a23af0e 0x3a234000 + 28430
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39a5ddec 0x39a46000 + 97772
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39a5d5ac 0x39a46000 + 95660
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a23ad46 0x3a234000 + 27974
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2c2de078 0x2c1d4000 + 1089656
10  Foundation                      0x2cf56e1e 0x2cf4c000 + 44574
11  XXX TRACKER                     0x000dedf2 0xda000 + 19954
12  CoreBluetooth                   0x2bfa04d6 0x2bf9d000 + 13526
13  CoreBluetooth                   0x2bfa096e 0x2bf9d000 + 14702
14  CoreBluetooth                   0x2bfab2a4 0x2bf9d000 + 58020
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7a4c80 0x3a7a3000 + 7296
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7a4c6c 0x3a7a3000 + 7276
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7af4ce 0x3a7a3000 + 50382
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7aed9c 0x3a7a3000 + 48540
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7b01b2 0x3a7a3000 + 53682
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2c2a3884 0x2c1d4000 + 850052
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2c2a1fa4 0x2c1d4000 + 843684
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2c1ed99c 0x2c1d4000 + 104860
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2c1ed7ae 0x2c1d4000 + 104366
24  GraphicsServices                0x3399f1a4 0x33996000 + 37284
25  UIKit                           0x2f978690 0x2f909000 + 456336
26  XXX TRACKER                     0x000df89e 0xda000 + 22686
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a7e2aac 0x3a7e1000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a89524c 0x3a894000 + 4684
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7b54ec 0x3a7a3000 + 74988
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7b521e 0x3a7a3000 + 74270

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8a99c0 0x3a894000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a926e20 0x3a926000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a926af8 0x3a926000 + 2808

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a89549c 0x3a894000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a895290 0x3a894000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2c2a37ee 0x2c1d4000 + 849902
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2c2a1db4 0x2c1d4000 + 843188
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2c1ed99c 0x2c1d4000 + 104860
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2c1ed7ae 0x2c1d4000 + 104366
6   CFNetwork                       0x2bd8b642 0x2bd0f000 + 509506
7   Foundation                      0x2d01c186 0x2cf4c000 + 852358
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a928de8 0x3a926000 + 11752
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a928d5a 0x3a926000 + 11610
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a926b04 0x3a926000 + 2820

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8a9080 0x3a894000 + 86144
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2c2a7fa0 0x2c1d4000 + 868256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a928de8 0x3a926000 + 11752
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a928d5a 0x3a926000 + 11610
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a926b04 0x3a926000 + 2820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3d1129dc      r6: 0x3d0fe840      r7: 0x001e7d38
    r8: 0x1768bfc0    r9: 0x7420666f     r10: 0x000e30fc     r11: 0x1768bfe4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x001e7d2c      lr: 0x3a929c97      pc: 0x3a8a8df0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xda000 - 0xe1fff XXX TRACKER armv7  <ed4b2a92bb693fbdbab907ff4a8acde9> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B4D46780-38A9-47EA-942F-AC997C6BB357/XXX TRACKER.app/XXX TRACKER
0x1fe61000 - 0x1fe84fff dyld armv7  <35ecdca1a767375e95ffa0f2a78d76d0> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2af75000 - 0x2af75fff Accelerate armv7  <a79992cca15033b7bed80bd705be71f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2af86000 - 0x2b19ffff vImage armv7  <872e53dd96dc36bf90b3a0ac74c5adb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x2b1a0000 - 0x2b27dfff libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3a6573adecda34749cc5282831e744cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2b27e000 - 0x2b541fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <1c01784b93d3329b97fc65515e51d5a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x2b542000 - 0x2b554fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7  <cebf63450c443b33815fa077775a1a11> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x2b555000 - 0x2b5c9fff libvDSP.dylib armv7  <3008dddb27c53aad952b3bbc6e640984> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2b5ca000 - 0x2b5dbfff libvMisc.dylib armv7  <39de9e92305734d9b8661d4d2981467d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x2b5dc000 - 0x2b5dcfff vecLib armv7  <6c07e6493c69320b8888af62c9702490> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x2b933000 - 0x2bba7fff AudioToolbox armv7  <35314493dec2370e88277f154701eecb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x2bd0f000 - 0x2be9bfff CFNetwork armv7  <9b5451d8ea3a395c9d85b29480c2b5dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x2bf22000 - 0x2bf81fff CoreAudio armv7  <2145d56fd7563bd9bc4a8261974aeec6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x2bf9d000 - 0x2bfbafff CoreBluetooth armv7  <1c0cd3e8d8b23164b1dff15acebc391e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x2c1d4000 - 0x2c506fff CoreFoundation armv7  <56d409e85e843dd98e7d3494112a0c35> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x2c507000 - 0x2c630fff CoreGraphics armv7  <097d6e7085893b518a4b07052fd170d5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x2c670000 - 0x2c672fff libCGXType.A.dylib armv7  <b18ea406878f326fa1f5735cd361cc16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x2c673000 - 0x2c67dfff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7  <2ca7a30774ea3073af7faf523b371911> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x2c865000 - 0x2c880fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <383be8976d58346191e245a0ed169b97> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x2c881000 - 0x2c993fff CoreImage armv7  <149e85c285313ece80f8f9ee5ec05f21> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x2ca1e000 - 0x2cabcfff CoreMedia armv7  <f6c07770f5503f6784ab5aa145d37c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x2cbfb000 - 0x2ccc7fff CoreText armv7  <06c12d17c87332e3a92fdd471c7460b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x2ccc8000 - 0x2ccdefff CoreVideo armv7  <2a18de158cf5384cb5f19b7f56231ceb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x2cf4c000 - 0x2d151fff Foundation armv7  <97042f0fe32f3ff1bee01cea7866d334> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x2d253000 - 0x2d2a8fff IOKit armv7  <c13d6573e7e83c75a88893c3e004e48c> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x2d2a9000 - 0x2d4f2fff ImageIO armv7  <cad9046aa04733a2a0e2eac058cd84af> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x2d4f3000 - 0x2d83dfff JavaScriptCore armv7  <9679b331fe0d331cb60fcf6182371f44> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x2db35000 - 0x2db3dfff MediaAccessibility armv7  <a807163c0ec33367ab1643971de5a910> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x2e160000 - 0x2e1cffff Metal armv7  <8e11a65349973e4eb041753af33687dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x2e1d0000 - 0x2e264fff MobileCoreServices armv7  <ee16e1530e7f367d973a716cfe88b1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x2edf8000 - 0x2ee00fff OpenGLES armv7  <7e510b8799793a1b820bf22def9975cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x2ee02000 - 0x2ee02fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2b49dae847f63c5682ddacdeadf08e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x2ee03000 - 0x2ee05fff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <324c3cef7d6d3e958a1f3a55e20e74f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x2ee06000 - 0x2ee09fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <2d35b7480ad03ee7b2ac3c6a03edcdec> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x2ee0a000 - 0x2ee12fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <8db068ab7c3131c38b62f97ebdd5f96a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x2ee13000 - 0x2ee52fff libGLImage.dylib armv7  <20469ae8ddd537d7a4177d24c81ff20a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x2f328000 - 0x2f484fff QuartzCore armv7  <8586510d30293a1db1e5a8e5f1efad21> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x2f6b9000 - 0x2f6fafff Security armv7  <2cb85f8b1c9e3a62b73841d04dd05e13> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x2f8aa000 - 0x2f906fff SystemConfiguration armv7  <8812238f38ed332f88803b8da35eb92b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x2f909000 - 0x301b7fff UIKit armv7  <ea23c036152530dd951a9b396153dcad> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x301b8000 - 0x3021ffff VideoToolbox armv7  <ba11ed2d070931b28a0f08cf663af71e> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30930000 - 0x30934fff AggregateDictionary armv7  <43803ef0c99337ad8e84b201cbd53be4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x30d02000 - 0x30d40fff AppSupport armv7  <e1706add1b26324fb9c8dc6fc3614f95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30e82000 - 0x30ec0fff AppleJPEG armv7  <2425baad41ae32538d38e5444dfb64f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x30f19000 - 0x30f22fff AssertionServices armv7  <8afeeca759fd39528c8c003fcbbe3c40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x30fa9000 - 0x30fc1fff BackBoardServices armv7  <5387378112d83ef3861b6f2bdb525d74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x30fc4000 - 0x30ff9fff BaseBoard armv7  <3ba2d91af0723d69b670a5916ab6a0a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x31ad8000 - 0x31adcfff ConstantClasses armv7  <d6d49478489a3e8fa14f11e460dd3934> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x31b98000 - 0x31bbafff CoreDuet armv7  <f23c4f48c0653e618e1fd7aa81bf9ae8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x31bc0000 - 0x31bd0fff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol armv7  <176f151714e635419978fe1c490aa835> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x31bd7000 - 0x31bd9fff CoreDuetDebugLogging armv7  <5b8e426276a73cf09b19d48a87fc475e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x31fcc000 - 0x31feafff CoreServicesInternal armv7  <dbeb8d004bf83d49a31d57fdbc7f964a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x321ea000 - 0x3226cfff CoreUI armv7  <1e8947c0cc213ed2946d536e13e13563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x322f2000 - 0x322f7fff CrashReporterSupport armv7  <5be916f2f61f343586b98c6b1d230273> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x325bf000 - 0x325d9fff DictionaryServices armv7  <93f47b91fb463c2a9129898cd3a185fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3274d000 - 0x32b70fff FaceCore armv7  <337307090c7738948561ba7e8eb5dacb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x32b98000 - 0x32b98fff FontServices armv7  <cbb30d45ea9734bfa6884f86a938a73f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x32b99000 - 0x32c6efff libFontParser.dylib armv7  <494ed59103ed36e997fb67e6066643e5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x32c6f000 - 0x32c7efff libGSFontCache.dylib armv7  <bd784593545d39de8954b379fcd0f3aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x32d62000 - 0x32d7efff FrontBoardServices armv7  <1e3e69f7a2b9312aa0678188baeaf4af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x33996000 - 0x339a6fff GraphicsServices armv7  <c5f9926d3a403f5997576e6e043cc70d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33f7d000 - 0x33f80fff IOAccelerator armv7  <dc084a6852df32c0bab91a7dfa2999b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x33f83000 - 0x33f89fff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <068bc120153632e19cf70b80b9d120ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33f8a000 - 0x33f8ffff IOSurface armv7  <66aec3303d453ee799985c1a92fc15b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33f90000 - 0x33f91fff IOSurfaceAccelerator armv7  <5874c3171d313b5fa3125ba47f08f60f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x34039000 - 0x34072fff LanguageModeling armv7  <989132d79a6b3605ac08181c299086ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x3453c000 - 0x34549fff MobileAsset armv7  <513173db2afc385d9bdb36c51ab0d8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x345a7000 - 0x345b3fff MobileKeyBag armv7  <ba62d597cb623cc0bef057768f4f16a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x345e0000 - 0x345e3fff MobileSystemServices armv7  <88ece9069dc231fcb625eecfa092c559> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x35083000 - 0x350bffff OpenCL armv7  <9e433d6013b933ffb34c8acb6ebefe93> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x35636000 - 0x35680fff PhysicsKit armv7  <f875279d5fe53e088a04e0537f753479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x35698000 - 0x3569ffff PowerLog armv7  <894fa9a13ee23ffc908c74c4dd4fd11f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x3599c000 - 0x35a32fff ProofReader armv7  <ef503c6ecf1d38019c86c5edeeffd9b7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35a96000 - 0x35b04fff Quagga armv7  <4c908b7b1c723f1baf4701b12a3035b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x35fef000 - 0x36009fff SpringBoardServices armv7  <bab3eb8a02e63c58816caa119a0eedae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36582000 - 0x36585fff TCC armv7  <d9a2a6b05bab3a8da9be98fa2aa2ad2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x371d7000 - 0x371fffff TextInput armv7  <bc6b4690669831c491b5cc158a43fd1b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x372bc000 - 0x3737efff UIFoundation armv7  <b95c82977904320ca9e5a46d34ddf634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x3739b000 - 0x3739efff UserFS armv7  <3b2efb8ace9234c1a5d30548618278e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x37c11000 - 0x3878ffff WebCore armv7  <9a857980242731b3b86ed88baf7764d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x38790000 - 0x3884efff WebKitLegacy armv7  <cf9deb949e44336498e1eadc4339124d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x394ef000 - 0x394f7fff libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d8223224f89531979ca64044e132cc64> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x39629000 - 0x3963ffff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <6c8b4c1a81be3031b11bb2c8df905bfc> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39672000 - 0x39775fff libFosl_dynamic.dylib armv7  <d3a22c809a2137df9759998fee35f7a5> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x3978f000 - 0x397a6fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <546035acb66b34fe8eb65a146ddd68fa> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x397cc000 - 0x397cdfff libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <08ff7c3cbd4e3e67993d0a48e6aed3fc> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x39992000 - 0x399b4fff libarchive.2.dylib armv7  <bb88ac87da0539deb475655459969c75> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x399e4000 - 0x399f0fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <5aacb51d3ab33eef96a210df170248aa> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x399f1000 - 0x399fafff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <3c8e4bd716963edeaed85a57f20d034e> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x399fb000 - 0x39a45fff libc++.1.dylib armv7  <809aa036ab31309c926ca9e6ebe6250a> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x39a46000 - 0x39a61fff libc++abi.dylib armv7  <406002273d8637abbaee6bac38172aa9> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x39a63000 - 0x39a70fff libcmph.dylib armv7  <5e36a49a7c7c348bba8c34a9c7949c31> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x39aa0000 - 0x39ab9fff libextension.dylib armv7  <1a01cb8a02303c3192303e971b6f6d9b> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x39bee000 - 0x39cdbfff libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <d2471d9b21d5391e9ebf48bdd3c535ed> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x39cdc000 - 0x39e4afff libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <c120e1f95861313a8f011280de2b5058> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x39e57000 - 0x39e57fff liblangid.dylib armv7  <3daf9c9e347e35488c42f7013b600555> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x39e58000 - 0x39e62fff liblockdown.dylib armv7  <a5d7dd55fc0434d69bffb76a88de209b> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x39e63000 - 0x39e78fff liblzma.5.dylib armv7  <b83d5e0f50b7392186780d7fa064b2b7> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x3a234000 - 0x3a42efff libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <59d299fcc23336749134265993dd48ee> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3a523000 - 0x3a5d3fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <674b23fdd5193544b3658ebe42c88772> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3a655000 - 0x3a70bfff libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <86ed8d560d153de3addfcad7374d30cc> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3a70c000 - 0x3a72dfff libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <0f99757ecf3a337996c29faf5f8e5dc1> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3a72e000 - 0x3a73afff libz.1.dylib armv7  <9f5e8650f96c351ab9c094e7a280aae2> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3a73b000 - 0x3a73ffff libcache.dylib armv7  <91080a77362f321aab9ee9355030dd3e> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3a740000 - 0x3a749fff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <81d06fb7445e3dc7ada75ed0b97003e0> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3a74a000 - 0x3a74efff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <791bcfcf3be332d583aec09e3ecce816> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3a74f000 - 0x3a755fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <b3781346554f328ea685999660cb7087> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3a756000 - 0x3a7a2fff libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <ab04a29c292630a89a5d37306720cffc> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3a7a3000 - 0x3a7e0fff libdispatch.dylib armv7  <7773602666b33c5fa7a42abc1f0426b4> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3a7e1000 - 0x3a7e2fff libdyld.dylib armv7  <94d89e576aeb386ebdfc40cccc32f2f1> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3a7e3000 - 0x3a7e3fff libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <f998ce3066a031f1a1e803d54f24fd2c> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3a7e4000 - 0x3a7e4fff liblaunch.dylib armv7  <60f1508df69c3927bd313c3064a8ac34> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3a7e5000 - 0x3a7e8fff libmacho.dylib armv7  <68c916315aa631adbaec0a8a42e338b4> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3a7e9000 - 0x3a7eafff libremovefile.dylib armv7  <193828d453763f91a9d9c91118fe29a5> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3a7eb000 - 0x3a7fcfff libsystem_asl.dylib armv7  <32c06053050f37988233ef007a20222e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x3a7fd000 - 0x3a7fdfff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <b4aba582daef30188b92ca1adbf0014c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3a7fe000 - 0x3a860fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f9bba36ff63532b7ab9416ad089b915c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3a861000 - 0x3a863fff libsystem_configuration.dylib armv7  <dfcd8a8b3e19374d9d9b92f9125ed23b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x3a864000 - 0x3a865fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib armv7  <9c170573a08b3e8ab8fd07cf3d5738a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x3a866000 - 0x3a872fff libsystem_coretls.dylib armv7  <0cfe7517b74438c2bb1aa146f27bd8c5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x3a873000 - 0x3a879fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <b74319a4cdb23c15827c30e3acfac206> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3a87a000 - 0x3a893fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <dac280dca30a3d8ea90f6ff7530c65f3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3a894000 - 0x3a8aefff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <bb8bc7dde0db32c7b450986eaef3f255> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3a8af000 - 0x3a8cffff libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <2ca83504dc863c2380ef4d837283d936> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3a8d0000 - 0x3a8e2fff libsystem_malloc.dylib armv7  <b4ac17518c163fe5b14d4e1bb8dad86a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x3a8e3000 - 0x3a911fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <6ca030ccb376302498cf989a98ba2056> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3a912000 - 0x3a917fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib armv7  <7636aa6643b13c178882862c65eb8098> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x3a918000 - 0x3a91ffff libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <114882d084cd38c1af8b91927fc70464> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3a920000 - 0x3a925fff libsystem_platform.dylib armv7  <4e61678a7d2b334bb08e058943ef2712> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x3a926000 - 0x3a92cfff libsystem_pthread.dylib armv7  <02d86fbb3e9434449f50d011aec33e43> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x3a92d000 - 0x3a92ffff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <978280d6072e394dbffb0285d9715c63> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3a930000 - 0x3a933fff libsystem_stats.dylib armv7  <0c0f198111183e69872af168499d8292> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
0x3a934000 - 0x3a939fff libsystem_trace.dylib armv7  <7c16daabde3e3596af2ca8ee9c6a5d8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x3a93a000 - 0x3a93afff libunwind.dylib armv7  <7a86e925589a3c6eb9bb604386a4498d> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3a93b000 - 0x3a956fff libxpc.dylib armv7  <89a85f226d7333d89d7afcf58d58c58e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: This is a de-symbolicated crash report, you need to symbolicate it to understand what it actually means. I would recommend you to go through this article http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1 to understand more about crash reports, their formants and understanding them

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav, I had a quick look. What I don't get is the guys are in Slovakia, I am in the UK, how did THEY get the reports and send them to me ? I gave them the app as a favor through ad-hoc procedure. Is what is described in the RW article going to work as this app hasn't been in the app store. I am completely confused.

Comment: you can export crash reports from device, connect it to xcode > windows > devices > select device and you can see crash reports

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, crash logs sent by the company needs to be symbolicated. I believe while you shipped your app, you might have saved `.dysm` file. Follow this procedure to get the exact root cause:

1. Gather your crash log and the dSYM file for your app.
2. Open a terminal and navigate to where you put your crash log and
   dSYM file. We'll call them `myapp.crash` and `myapp.app.dSYM`
3. Run `sudo xcode-select --switch
   /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer`
4. Finally, run : `DEVELOPER_DIR=`xcode-select -print-path`/Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -o ./myapp-resymbolicated.crash ./myapp.crash ./myapp.app.dSYM`

**Second**, you would want to check with the company the tentative steps to reproduce the crash. Then try on your own with those steps.

**Third**, my advise to you is to include a crash reporter in your application for next release. Crash reporter uploads crash reports on your server in symbolicated form which really helps to crack the issue. Take a look at this [blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1) in your lean time.

*To answer your questions:*

1. When application crashes, you can get the crash logs by connecting the device to system and opening ogranizer in Xcode.
2. EXC_CRASH is a mach exception that just means the application terminated abnormally. Mostly its because of un-handled exception. You have to symbolicate your crash log to debug this further

Comment: Thank you Abhinav. 
Regarding your "to answer your questions" part, what I don't understand in point 1 is that you say "I can get the crash logs by connecting the device to system and open organizer in Xcode". 
You mean even if the crash didn't happen on my device? I am sorry I have apps in the app store, but I am lucky enough they never crashed (so far), that's why I am so confused.

Comment: No you have to have the device to get the crash report in this way - by "you" Abhinav meant the person who wants to get a crash report from the device. This was in answer to your question "how did they get a crash report?"